# center align Android Action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble center-aligning my logo and text for an android project. Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <!-- Actionbar style -->
    <style name="Widget.project.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Elmwood.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Elmwood.TitleTextStyle</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/project_blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/project_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Elmwood.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.project.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.project.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <style name="BlueBackgroundButtonLargeWhiteTextButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/project_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/title_text_padding</item>
    </style>

    <style name="InnerCircleDetailButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/inner_circle_button</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="InnerCircleContinueButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/black_grey_button_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/normal_text</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HomepageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
    <!-- end Buttons -->

    <!-- ListViews -->
    <style name="projectBlueListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/project_blue_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StandardListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
    <!-- end ListViews -->

    <!-- TextViews -->
    <style name="TitleTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleTextViewWhite" parent="@style/TitleTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/normal_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTextViewBold" parent="@style/NormalTextView">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTextViewWhite" parent="@style/NormalTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTextViewGrey" parent="@style/NormalTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/project_grey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="projectListItemTitleTextView" parent="@style/NormalTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="projectListItemNumberTextView" parent="@style/NormalTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/project_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    </style>
    <!-- end TextViews -->


</resources>
```

I can do *some* modifications; For instance if I remove

```
<item name="android:background">@color/project_blue</item>
<item name="background">@color/project_blue</item>
```

I get a plain white action bar, but nothing I do whatsoever will allow me to change the alignment of either the text or the logo. Both need to be center aligned.

I've looked up multiple solutions to this problem and all of them say the same thing; I need to make a custom layout which to m knowledge I already have. No changes I make to any XML files will change the alignment whatsoever.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

I've already tried adding a custom action bar but it didn't work. While I can get it to appear, it won't respond to centre-alignment at all.

This is in my onCreate():

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null));
```

and this is my custom_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/slideMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I can change the icons and stuff so I know it is at least responing to changes, but attempting to align it results in nothing.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no possibility to center horizontally your logo and title with standard actionbar. You have to:

1. use your fully custom ActionBar
   or
2. add custom view to standard action bar imitating logo + title.

   `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
   actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout_with_logo_and_title);`

Comment: I've already tried this to no avail. I can get it to show a custom layout, but it won't respond to any attempts to centre-align anything.